# Minimize $P=\dfrac{\sqrt{a+1}+\sqrt{b+1}+\sqrt{c+1}}{\sqrt{ab+bc+ca+6}},$ if $a+b+c+abc=4.$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, maxima-minima

> **Problem.** Let $a,b,c\ge 0: a+b+c+abc=4.$ Find minimal value of $P$ $$P=\frac{\sqrt{a+1}+\sqrt{b+1}+\sqrt{c+1}}{\sqrt{ab+bc+ca+6}}.$$
> Source: Vo Quoc Ba Can.

---

*My attempt:*

Set $$P(a,b,c)=\frac{\sqrt{a+1}+\sqrt{b+1}+\sqrt{c+1}}{\sqrt{ab+bc+ca+6}}.$$

After some calculating works, I've tried prove $P(1,1,1)$ is the minimal value.

It means that we need to prove $$\sqrt{a+1}+\sqrt{b+1}+\sqrt{c+1}\ge\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{ab+bc+ca+6}.$$
By squaring both side, it remains to prove $$a+b+c+3+2\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{(a+1)(b+1)}\ge 2(ab+bc+ca+6),$$or $$2\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{(a+1)(b+1)}\ge 5+abc+2(ab+bc+ca).$$
I was stucked here. Hope to see some ideas to continue the idea.

Also, all answer and comment are welcome. Thank for your attention.

Updated edit: Thank you @138 Aspen. I made a mistake in calculating.

Minimum should be $$P(0,2,2)=\frac{2\sqrt{30}+\sqrt{10}}{10}.$$

It means that we need to prove $$\sqrt{a+1}+\sqrt{b+1}+\sqrt{c+1}\ge\frac{2\sqrt{30}+\sqrt{10}}{10}\cdot\sqrt{ab+bc+ca+6},$$which seems ugly. Hope MV (mixing variables) technique works.

Comment: Have you tried a change of variables like $a' = a +1$, $b' = b +1$, $c' = c+1$? It looks like it would simplify the expression...

Comment: @Surge It is a good idea

Comment: `f[a_, b_, c_] := (Sqrt[a + 1] + Sqrt[b + 1] + Sqrt[c + 1])/
  Sqrt[a*b + b*c + c*a + 6]
constraint = a + b + c + a*b*c == 4 && a >= 0 && b >= 0 && c >= 0

solution = Reduce[constraint, {a, b, c}, Reals]

minimum = NMinimize[{f[a, b, c], solution}, {a, b, c}]`


Mathematica shows (a,b,c)=(2,2,0) or (2,0,2) or (0,2,2) may minimize $P$

Comment: @138Aspen Thanks. I'll check it clearly.

Comment: @TATAbox Nevertheless, $(a,b,c)=(1,1,1)$ seems very close to the minimum.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Yes, it's a big trouble.

Comment: @138Aspen Does your software give some idea to solve the problem ?

Comment: @TATAbox perhaps Jensen's inequality can help you. Can you figure something out by looking at the polynomial whose roots are $a,b$ and $c$?

Comment: Yes, (2,2,0) etc give the minima. Here's a 3D sketch: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxVUUFOwzAQvOcVK3GInZoSl6itEL5yrHrghhBauw4JJLFruyDxetahKnCIM7s7MztOPjCwEoUuebHDCRS0g8PEyh3uqGWowRq4BqRHc7gBJmEBWGleeJrFY0gMqSM5HXOl%5F1VmroojcUlEha5yy1RZtJ49PLnO3CMvioNtwbQMBW27KwCCTacwnUMZhipPlOY5SvND%5F8O%2D8GVd%2DV8y9C3gQsO9ggbsEC3QVUnsRlpfCzLa5xyDS7cH1grIhhVNOUF9gcYNLihm2jMc0celHzCOyAUtz%5FoX7%5FopRbUm19HGTj0graN7dfnLspWAFYcrWUMFctlIud6stltZrzZyQxkWFCLrKcUTIweidzkDvetfOHefBcT%2Dy6otL%5FbL2LlP1gYcrXoMJysgdZZwecDwXgrwwb1Zk3o3qdKF1LnXgL7rDf3fb%2DJZiGc=&lang=sage

Comment: @PM2Ring Thank you.

Comment: A standard technique for constrained minimisation is Lagrange multipliers. I have a solution for a similar (but simpler) problem here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3881512/207316

Comment: I think the reasoning is prove the OP in case two equal variables.

Comment: @TATAbox Since it is Vo Quoc Ba Can's problem, it should have a smooth/nice proof? I have a proof which is not nice.

Comment: @RiverLi The author hasn't revealed the official solution yet. It would be great if you share your idea.

Comment: @TATAbox I will post it if no solution in some days.

Comment: @RiverLi I am not sure that $P(0,2,2)$ is minimum because I didn't know how to use computer system check. Is  that $\dfrac{2\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{10}}{10}$ true?

Comment: @TATAbox Yes, $P(2,2,0)$ is the minimum.

Comment: @RiverLi It's really confusing because (a,b,c)=(1,1,1)
 seems very close to the minimum.

Comment: @TATAbox Yes, the difference is 0.0025.

Comment: @TATAbox It seem unsual the problem should be public soon. VQBC submitted it for a contest.

Comment: @Inequality Yes, one friend of mine told me that the commitee has denied it. That's why I post it here for serious discussion.

Comment: What is  Vo Quoc Ba Can? Is it a live competition framework where people must stay in a closed room and work with paper and pen only solutions to such problems? Or people are at home and can consult everybody in the world, every book, and use any computer aids?

Comment: @dan_fulea He is a famous inequality author and his problems are nice with elegant solutions. The original inequality is one of them.

Comment: Can we use LM ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Two approaches.**

**Approach 1.**

We may use Holder, similar to my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4725605/a-b-c-ge-0-abcabc-4-prove-that-sum-cyc-sqrt-fracabcab-ge-3).

It suffices to prove that
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\sqrt{\frac{a + 1}{ab + bc + ca + 6}} \ge \frac{2\sqrt{30} + \sqrt{10}}{10}.$$

If $\max(a, b, c) = 4$, clearly the inequality is true. In the following, assume that $\max(a, b, c) < 4$.

By Holder, we have
\begin{align*}
 &\Big(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\sqrt{\frac{a + 1}{ab + bc + ca + 6}}\Big)^2
  \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (a + 1)^2(ab + bc + ca + 6)(ab + \sqrt{3}\, bc + ca)^3\\[6pt]
 &\ge \left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (a + 1)(ab + \sqrt{3}\, bc + ca)\right)^3. \tag{1}
\end{align*}

It suffices to prove that
\begin{align*}
 &\left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (a + 1)(ab + \sqrt{3}\, bc + ca)\right)^3\\
 \ge{}& \left(\frac{2\sqrt{30} + \sqrt{10}}{10}\right)^2 \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (a + 1)^2(ab + bc + ca + 6)(ab + \sqrt{3}\, bc + ca)^3. \tag{2}
\end{align*}
(2) is true which is verified by *Mathematica* - a Computer Algebra System.

$\phantom{2}$

**Approach 2.**

**Fact 1.** Let $p, q, r \ge 0$ with $p^2 \ge 3q$ and $r \ge \frac{4pq - p^3}{9}$ and $p^2 + 4pr + 2qr + r^2 + 2p - 2q + 8r - 4 = 0$. Then
$$\frac{(3 + p)^2}{2pq - 2pr + q^2 + 4q - 6r + 6} \ge \frac{13 + 4\sqrt 3}{10}.$$
(It is verified by *Mathematica* (a Computer Algebra System).)

Let
\begin{align*}
 p &:= (\sqrt{a+1} - 1) + (\sqrt{b + 1} - 1) + (\sqrt{c + 1} - 1), \\
 q &:= \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (\sqrt{1 + a} - 1)(\sqrt{1 + b} - 1), \\
 r &:= (\sqrt{1 + a} - 1)(\sqrt{1 + b} - 1)(\sqrt{1 + c} - 1).
\end{align*}
(*Note*: Letting $x = \sqrt{a+1} - 1$, $y = \sqrt{b + 1} - 1$ and $z = \sqrt{c + 1} - 1$, we have $p = x + y + z, q = xy + yz + zx, r = xyz$.)

Clearly, we have $p^2 \ge 3q$, and $r \ge \frac{4pq - p^3}{9}$ (degree three Schur).
Also, we have
$$p^2 + 4pr + 2qr + r^2 + 2p - 2q + 8r - 4 = a + b + c + abc - 4 = 0.$$
Moreover, we have
$$\frac{(3 + p)^2}{2pq - 2pr + q^2 + 4q - 6r + 6} = \frac{(\sqrt{a+1}+\sqrt{b+1}+\sqrt{c+1})^2}{ab+bc+ca+6}.$$
By Fact 1, we have
$$ \frac{(\sqrt{a+1}+\sqrt{b+1}+\sqrt{c+1})^2}{ab+bc+ca+6}
\ge \frac{13 + 4\sqrt 3}{10}.$$

Comment: It's interesting. Thank you and +1

Answer (score 4):

> It means that we need to prove $$\sqrt{a+1}+\sqrt{b+1}+\sqrt{c+1}\ge\frac{2\sqrt{30}+\sqrt{10}}{10}\cdot\sqrt{ab+bc+ca+6},$$

Put $M=\left(\frac{2\sqrt{30}+\sqrt{10}}{10}\right)^2$, $x=\sqrt{a+1}\ge 1$, $y=\sqrt{b+1}\ge 1$, and $z=\sqrt{c+1}\ge 1$.

Thus we need to show $(x+y+z)^2\ge M(ab+bc+ca+6)$.

We have $$x^2+y^2+z^2=a+b+c+3,$$
$$x^2y^2z^2=(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)=$$ $$abc+ab+bc+ca+a+b+c+1=ab+bc+ca+5,$$
$$x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2=$$ $$(a+1)(b+1)+(b+1)(c+1)+(c+1)(a+1)=$$
$$ab+bc+ca+2(a+b+c)+3=$$ $$ab+bc+ca+2(x^2+y^2+z^2)-3.$$

Thus we have to show that

$$(x+y+z)^2\ge M(x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2-2(x^2+y^2+z^2)+9)$$

provided $x,y,z\ge 1$ and $$x^2y^2z^2-5=x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2-2(x^2+y^2+z^2)+3.$$

Maybe this can be achieved using Lagrange's multipliers.

Comment: The idea is similar to mine. I used $x := \sqrt{a + 1} - 1$ etc. then use pqr. By the way, I use this substitution in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4746266/if-xyyzzxxyz-4-prove-frac1-sqrtx1-frac1-sqrty1-frac1/4746480#4746480)

Answer (score 2):

*Remarks*: I found a proof better than my two old approaches. We use the so-called isolated fudging.
For my answers using isolated fudging, see e.g.
[P1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4653507/prove-a-sqrt-log-bab-sqrt-log-cbc-sqrt-log-ac-geqslant-abc/4655343#4655343),
[P2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4747800/prove-frac1-sqrt3xy3-ge-2-sqrt3-left-frac1-sqrtx2-frac1/4748020#4748020), [P3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3263143/prove-sum-limits-mathrmcyc-sqrt1-ab-ge-2-sqrt2-for-a-b-c-ge-0-with/4727302#4727302).

We need to prove that
$$\sqrt{a + 1} + \sqrt{b + 1} + \sqrt{c + 1}
\ge \frac{2\sqrt{30} + \sqrt{10}}{10}
\cdot \sqrt{ab + bc + ca + 6}. \tag{1}$$

Let $C := \big(\frac{2\sqrt{30} + \sqrt{10}}{10}\big)^2$.
Squaring both sides of (1), it suffices to prove that
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} 2\sqrt{a + 1}\sqrt{b + 1}
\ge C(ab + bc + ca + 6) - a - b - c - 3. \tag{2}$$

Let
\begin{align*}
 f(a, b, c) &:= \frac{\sqrt{3} + 2}{5}abc + \frac{129 - 28\sqrt{3}}{90}ab + \frac{16\sqrt{3} - 3}{45}(a + b)c\\[6pt]
 &\qquad + \frac{14\sqrt{3} + 3}{45}(a + b) + \frac{3 - \sqrt 3}{45}c.
\end{align*}
We have
\begin{align*}
 &C(ab + bc + ca + 6) - a - b - c - 3
 - \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} f(a, b, c)\\
 ={}& - \frac35(2 +\sqrt 3)(a + b + c + abc - 4)\\[6pt]
 ={}& 0. \tag{3}
\end{align*}

Using (3), (2) is written as
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \left(2\sqrt{a + 1}\sqrt{b + 1} - f(a, b, c)\right) \ge 0. \tag{4}$$

**Fact 1.** Let $x, y, z \ge 0$ with $x + y + z + xyz = 4$. Then
$$2\sqrt{x + 1}\sqrt{y + 1} - f(x, y, z) \ge 0.$$
(The proof is given at the end.)

By Fact 1, letting $x = a, y = b, z = c$, we have
$2\sqrt{a + 1}\sqrt{b + 1} - f(a, b, c) \ge 0$;
letting $x = b, y = c, z = a$, we have
$2\sqrt{b + 1}\sqrt{c + 1} - f(b, c, a)\ge 0$; letting $x = c, y = a, z = b$, we have $2\sqrt{c+1}\sqrt{a+1} - f(c, a, b) \ge 0$. Thus, (4) is true.

We are done.

$\phantom{2}$

---

*Proof of Fact 1.*

We need to prove that
\begin{align*}
 2\sqrt{xy + x + y + 1} &\ge \frac{\sqrt{3} + 2}{5}xyz + \frac{129 - 28\sqrt{3}}{90}xy + \frac{16\sqrt{3} - 3}{45}(x + y)z\\[6pt]
 &\qquad + \frac{14\sqrt{3} + 3}{45}(x + y) + \frac{3 - \sqrt 3}{45}z. \tag{A1}
\end{align*}

Let $p = x + y, q = xy$. Then $0 \le p \le 4$, $q \ge 0$ and $p^2\ge 4q$. Using $z = \frac{4 - x - y}{1 + xy} = \frac{4 - p}{1 + q}$, (A1) is equivalently written as
\begin{align*}
 180(1 + q)\sqrt{p + q + 1} &\ge
  ( 129-28\sqrt {3} ) {q}^{2} + ( 10\sqrt {3}\,p+44
 \sqrt {3}-30p+273 ) q\\
 &\quad -32\,\sqrt {3}{p}^{2}+158\,\sqrt {3}p+6\,
 {p}^{2}-8\,\sqrt {3}-24\,p+24.\tag{A2}
\end{align*}
Let $F(q) := \mathrm{LHS}_{(A2)} - \mathrm{RHS}_{(A2)}$. We have, for all $0 \le q \le p^2/4$,
\begin{align*}
 F''(q) &= \frac{45(4p + 3q + 3)}{(p + q + 1)^{3/2}} - 258 + 56\sqrt{3} \\
 &\le \frac{45(4p + 3\cdot p^2/4 + 3)}{(p  + 1)^{3/2}} - 258 + 56\sqrt{3}\\
 &< 0.
\end{align*}
Thus, $F(q)$ is concave on $[0, p^2/4]$.
Also, we have $F(0) \ge 0$ and $F(p^2/4) \ge 0$ (easy), for all $0\le p \le 4$.
Thus, $F(q) \ge 0$ on $[0, p^2/4]$, given any $0 \le p\le 4$.

We are done.

Comment: Wow, it's nice! +1\

Answer (score 1):

We have for $x\in[0,2]$ :

$$\sqrt{x+1}\geq g(x)=\frac{\left(1-\sqrt{3}\right)}{0-2}x+1+\frac{1}{8}\frac{x\left(2-x\right)}{x+2}+\frac{1}{3}\frac{x^{2}\left(2-x\right)}{\left(x+2\right)^{4}}$$

Then :

$$a(x,y,z)=(g(x)+g(y)+g(z))^{2}-\left(\frac{2\sqrt{30}+\sqrt{10}}{10}\right)^2(xy+yz+zx+6)$$

Then it seems that all the coefficient are positive in :

$$a\left(\frac{2x}{x+1},\frac{2y}{y+1},\frac{2(x+y+2)}{5xy+x+y+1}\right)$$

Ps: it's painful need a software better than Geogebra.

If you want to check  it's all positive .(false)

Another way :

We have for $x\in[0,2]$ :

$$\sqrt{x+1}\geq g(x)=\frac{\left(1-\sqrt{3}\right)}{0-2}x+1+\frac{1}{8}\frac{x\left(2-x\right)}{x+2}+\frac{1}{\left(16\left(7+4\sqrt{3}\right)\right)}x\left(2-x\right)$$

We have for $x\in[3,4]$ :

$$f\left(x\right)=\sqrt{x+6}\leq h\left(x\right)=\frac{\left(x+6\right)}{\left(f\left(4\right)-f\left(3\right)\right)\left(x-4\right)+f\left(4\right)}$$

Then it seems true that :

$$a(x,y,z)=(g(x)+g(y)+g(z))-\left(\frac{2\sqrt{30}+\sqrt{10}}{10}\right)h\left(xy+yz+zx\right),a\left(\frac{2x}{x+1},\frac{2y}{y+1},\frac{2(x+y+2)}{5xy+x+y+1}\right)\geq 0$$

Can someone check (I check  it's positive for $x\geq 1,y\geq 1$ as we have some constraint on the bound above):

$$a\left(\frac{2x}{x+1},\frac{2y}{y+1},\frac{2(x+y+2)}{5xy+x+y+1}\right)>0$$

Using Am-Gm it's not hard to show it's positive for $x\geq 1,y\geq 1$ it's a bit lenghty .

Using Jensen's inequality :

define :

$$g(x)=\frac{\left(1-\sqrt{3}\right)}{0-2}x+1+\frac{1}{8}\frac{x\left(2-x\right)}{x+2}+\frac{1}{\left(16\left(7+4\sqrt{3}\right)\right)}x\left(2-x\right),t\left(x\right)=\left(x+2+\frac{1}{x+d}\right)g\left(x\right),h\left(x\right)=\left(x+2+\frac{1}{x+d}\right)\left(g\left(x\right)-\frac{t''\left(0\right)x^{2}}{2\left(x+2+\frac{1}{x+d}\right)}\right)$$

Such that : $$h''(0)=h''(2)=0,d\simeq 6$$

Then we have $x,y\in[1,\infty)$:

$$d\left(x,y\right)>b\left(x,y\right)$$

Where :

$$l\left(x,y,z\right)=\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{y+1}+\sqrt{z+1}-\frac{\left(2\sqrt{30}+\sqrt{10}\right)}{10}\left(\sqrt{6+xy+yz+zx}\right),d\left(x,y\right)=l\left(\frac{2x}{x+1},\frac{2y}{y+1},\frac{2(x+y+2)}{5xy+x+y+1}\right)$$

And :

$$a\left(x,y,z\right)=\left(\frac{1}{m\left(x\right)}+\frac{1}{m\left(y\right)}+\frac{1}{m\left(z\right)}\right)\left(h\left(\frac{\left(\frac{x}{m\left(x\right)}+\frac{y}{m\left(y\right)}+\frac{z}{m\left(z\right)}\right)}{\frac{1}{m\left(x\right)}+\frac{1}{m\left(y\right)}+\frac{1}{m\left(z\right)}}\right)\right)-\frac{\left(2\sqrt{30}+\sqrt{10}\right)}{10}\left(xy+yz+zx+6\right)\cdot\frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{10}-3\right)\left(xy+yz+zx-4\right)+\sqrt{10}}+\frac{j\left(x\right)}{m\left(x\right)}+\frac{j\left(y\right)}{m\left(y\right)}+\frac{j\left(z\right)}{m\left(z\right)},m\left(x\right)=\left(x+2+\frac{1}{x+6}\right),b\left(x,y\right)=a\left(\frac{2x}{x+1},\frac{2y}{y+1},\frac{2(x+y+2)}{5xy+x+y+1}\right),j\left(x\right)=\frac{t''\left(0\right)x^{2}}{2}$$

Comment: The bound is fine. It is not true that all coefficients are non-negative because you forgot the square of $\left(\frac{2\sqrt{30}+\sqrt{10}}{10}\right)$. It is a horribly long expression.  You need to prove it.

Comment: @RiverLi it's a typo and the problem seems now monstruous

Comment: Did you check the coefficients? I checked 9 hours ago. It is not true all the coefficients are non-negative.

Comment: @RiverLi I can not check it by eyes

Comment: @TATAbox My checking shows there are negative coefficients. I think it is difficult to prove that the expression is non-negative. I am interested in a proof which is human verifiable. Sometimes, we use computer to motivate a proof (perhaps very difficult to motivate it by hand), however the proof itself can be verified even by hand. Here, it is too complicated to verify it if all coefficients are not non-negative.

Comment: @RiverLi Yes you are right I shall propose something else

Comment: @Wolframandgromit You may use simpler bounds.

Comment: @RiverLi Done ! But I cannot check with Geogebra (some problem with the sotware)

Comment: @RiverLi I show the equality case and the case $(1,1,1)$ but it's partial . This problem is a nightmare .

Comment: @Wolframandgromit I suggest you do not put the very very long expression here. It is expected of you to find a simple solution.

Comment: @RiverLi Perhaps have you a proof using $pqr$ method using all the work here?

Comment: @Wolframandgromit You can try. It is too complicated for your expression.

Comment: @RiverLi for $x,y\in[1,16]$ we have : $$t\left(x\right)=\left(x+2+\frac{x}{x+\frac{1}{2}}\right)g\left(x\right),m\left(x\right)=\left(x+2+\frac{x}{x+\frac{1}{2}}\right),f\left(x\right)=\sqrt{x+6},h\left(x\right)=\frac{\left(x+6\right)}{\left(f\left(4\right)-f\left(3\right)\right)\left(x-4\right)+f\left(4\right)},g(x)=\frac{\left(1-\sqrt{3}\right)}{0-2}x+1+\frac{1}{8}\frac{x\left(2-x\right)}{x+2}+\frac{1}{\left(16\left(7+4\sqrt{3}\right)\right)}x\left(2-x\right)$$ then we have : $$c\left(x,y,z\right)=a\left(\frac{2x}{x+1},\frac{2y}{y+1},\frac{2(x+y+2)}{5xy+x+y+1}\right)>0$$ where.....

Comment: Where $$a(x,y,z)=\left(\frac{1}{m\left(x\right)}+\frac{1}{m\left(y\right)}+\frac{1}{m\left(z\right)}\right)t\left(\frac{\frac{x}{m\left(x\right)}+\frac{y}{m\left(y\right)}+\frac{z}{m\left(z\right)}}{\frac{1}{m\left(x\right)}+\frac{1}{m\left(y\right)}+\frac{1}{m\left(z\right)}}\right)-\left(\frac{2\sqrt{30}+\sqrt{10}}{10}\right)\left(\frac{6+xy+yz+zx}{\left(f\left(4\right)-f\left(3\right)\right)\left(xy+yz+zx-4\right)+f\left(4\right)}\right)$$

Comment: Using Jensen's inequality on $t\left(x\right)=\left(x+2+\frac{x}{x+\frac{1}{2}}\right)g\left(x\right)$

Comment: Correction we can use Jensen's inequality for $x\in[1,10],y\in[1,2]$ and $$t\left(x\right)=\left(\frac{x}{2}+1.5+\frac{x}{x+2}\right)g\left(x\right)$$ instead of the $t(x)$ just above it simplify the current lengthy expression above .

Answer (score 1):

Let us rewrite. We are searching the minimal value of the expression
$$
P(a,b,c)=
\frac
{\sqrt{a+1} + \sqrt{b+1} + \sqrt{c+1}}
{\sqrt{(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)+1}}
$$
constrained to the relation $a+b+c+abc=4$.
It turns out it is $\sqrt K$,
$$
P(a,b,c)\ge \sqrt K\ ,\qquad K=\frac1{10}(1+2\sqrt 3)^2=\frac 1{10}(13+2\sqrt 7)\approx 1.9928203230275\dots\ \ .
$$
Let us show this.

---

It is convenient to substitute $x,y,z\ge 1$ for $\sqrt{a+1}$, $\sqrt{b+1}$, $\sqrt{c+1}$.
And let us use the symmetric elementary functions $p,q,r$ for the variables $x,y,z$, so $p=x+y+z$, $q=xy+yz+zx$, $r=xyz$.
The relation satisfied by $x,y,z$ is:
$$
x^2y^2z^2 -x^2y^2 -y^2z^2-z^2x^2 +2x^2+2y^2+2z^2-8=0\ .
$$
In terms of $p,q,r$ it is:
$$
r^2 -(q^2-2pr)+2(p^2-2q)-8=0\ .
$$
So we solve a related problem first, we minimize the following function
$F$ on the domain $p\ge 3$, $q\ge 3$, $r\ge 1$, $p^2\ge 3p$ (which is $\sum(x-y)^2\ge 0$ with equality iff $x=y=z$), and $p(p^2-3q) + 6r\ge pq-3r$ (which is $x^3+y^3+z^3+3xyz\ge x^2(y+z)+y^2(z+x)+z^3(x+y)$, Schur). Note that the Schur inequality becomes an equality if and only if two involved variables are equal, this is also the case we obtain equality in $P\ge \sqrt K$. We restate this as $P^2\ge K$, and further as $(x+y+z)^2\ge K(x^2y^2z^2+1)$. So we consider the minimization of $F$,
$$ 
F(p,q,r):=p^2-K(r^2+1)\ ,
\qquad\text{ constrained to }
\underbrace{r^2-(q^2-2pr)+2(p^2-2q)-8}_{h(p,q,r)}=0\ .
$$

---

Lagrange multiplicators. In case of a **local** extremal value in the domain (two-dimensional) $h(p,q,r)=0$, with boundaries given by the above boundary conditions, the coresponding extremal point satisfies $0=G'_p=G'_q=G'_r=G'_m$ for
$$
G(p,q,r;m):=
F(p,q,r)-mh(p,q,r)\ .
$$
The corresponding system is:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
0&=2p-m(2r+4p)\ ,\\
0&=-m(-2q-4)\ ,\\
0&=-2Kr-m(2r+2p)\ ,\\
0&=h(p,q,r)\ .
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
The condition $0=G'_q$ makes everything clear. ($F$ does not depend on $q$.) The factor $2q+4$ does not vanish in the given region. Also, $m=0$ leads to $p=r=0$, again outside of the sight. So any extremal value for $F$ constrained to $h=0$ is a boundary point.

Each of the boundary conditions $p=3$ and/or $q=3$ and/or $r=1$ and/or $p^2=3q$ leads to $x=y=z$ thus to $a=b=c$, and the common value is $1$ from the given $(a,b,c)$-condition. In this case $x=y=z=\sqrt 2$, $p=3\sqrt 2$, $r=2\sqrt 2$, and
$$
\begin{aligned}
F(3\sqrt 2,*,2\sqrt 2)
&=(3\sqrt 2)^2-K((2\sqrt2)^2+1)=18-9K=9(2-K)
\\
&=
\frac 9{10} (7-4\sqrt 3)
=\frac 9{10} \cdot \frac {49-48}{7+4\sqrt 3}
>0\ .e
\end{aligned}
$$

---

It remains to check the remained boundary condition, the Schur condition on $p,q,r$, taken with equality. This happens iff two values among $x,y,z$ (equivalently among $a,b,c$) are equal. Here, we can go back to $P$, assume $a=c$, write $b$ in terms of $a$ as $b=b(a)=2(2-a)/(a^2+1)$, so $a\in[0,2]$, and minimize the ugly function in one variable

$$a\to g(a)=\Bigg( \ 2\sqrt{a+1} +\sqrt{b(a)+1}\ \Bigg)^2-K\Bigg(\ 1 + (a+1)\sqrt{b(a)+1} \ \Bigg)\ , \qquad g:[0,2]\to\Bbb R\ .
$$
In a plot:

[image: mse problem 4799787]

I hope, everybody who considered the problem will find from here her or his way to proceed.

---

Humanly, the problem starts now, i have no chance to finish in time as a human. The reason is the following one. We have a more or less complicated function. Its study must somehow involve analytic tools like taking derivatives, consider critical points, compute the value in these points. Then also compute the values at the ends of the interval $[0,2]$, and finally decide which candidate wins the minimum prize.

Well, this consideration must then find the critical point $a=1$, which is easy to check in any system of equations, but also that local max between $1$ and $ 2$. And this point is no longer "easy".
So let us work algebraically with the aid of a computer.
We are searching for globally minimal points $(a,b,c)$ for $P$ with $a=c$.
Let us pass to the $(x,y,z)$ coordinates via $a=x^2-1$, $b=y^2-1$, the condition $a=c$ becomes $x=z$, so we want to minimize
$$
\begin{aligned}
F(x,y ) &= (2x+y)^2-K(x^4y^2+1)\ ,\\
&\qquad\text{ constrained to }
\\
0 &= \underbrace{2(x^2-1)+(y^2-1)+(x^2-1)^2(y^2-1)-4}_{h(x,y)}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
We have two new functions $F,h$. Lagrange multiplicators for them.
We obtain an ugly algebraic system of high degree. Let us ask the
machine for solutions with $x,y\ge 1$.

```
L.<w> = QuadraticField(3)
K = (1 + 2*w)^2/10
R.<x, y, m> = PolynomialRing(L)

F = (2*x + y)^2 - K*(x^4*y^2 + 1)
h = 2*(x^2 - 1) + (y^2 - 1) + (x^2 - 1)^2*(y^2 - 1) - 4

J = R.ideal([diff(F - m*h, v) for v in (x, y, m)])
variety = J.variety(ring=AA)
for dic in variety:
    x0, y0, m0 = dic[x], dic[y], dic[m]
    if not(x0 >= 1 and y0 >= 1):
        continue
    a0, b0 = x0^2 - 1, y0^2 -1
    print(f"Critical point with components:")
    print(f"(x, y) = ({x0}, {y0})")
    print(f"(a, b) = ({a0}, {b0})")
    print(f"    F-value = {F.subs(x=x0, y=y0)}")
```

And we obtain:

```
Critical point with components:
(x, y) = (1.414213562373095?, 1.414213562373095?)
(a, b) = (1, 1)
    F-value = 0.06461709275204174?
Critical point with components:
(x, y) = (1.610339275596270?, 1.109030006353267?)
(a, b) = (1.593192582527918?, 0.2299475549919257?)
    F-value = 0.2710105546461977?
```

This values are now compared with the values at the extremities of the interval, and the value in $(a,b)=(2,0)$, corresponding to $(x,y)=(\sqrt 3,1)$ wins, the function $F$ is zero, the global minimum.

Comment: I have some questions. (1) There are some typos. 
It should be $K=\frac1{10}(1+2\sqrt 3)^2=\frac 1{10}(13+{\color{red} {4\sqrt{3}}})$
and $p^2 \ge {\color{red} {3q}}$.

Comment: (2) You want to minimize $F(p, q, r) = p^2 - K(r^2 + 1)$ on the domain $p\ge 3, q \ge 3, r \ge 1, p^2 \ge 3q$ and $p(p^2 - 3q) + 6r \ge pq - 3r$ and $r^2 -(q^2-2pr)+2(p^2-2q)-8=0$.
However, $F(p, q, r)$ can be negative on this domain. For example, when $p = 6, q = 11, r = \sqrt{137} - 6$,
all the condition above are met; However, $F(6, 11, \sqrt{137} - 6) = -30.84636990$. See next comment.

Comment: The reason is that: This domain is only a subset of the original domain, which is not enough for $F(p, q, r) \ge 0$ (the original domain is enough, certainly). For a $(p, q, r)$ in your domain, when we solve the cubic $u^3 - pu^2 + qu - r = 0$ for $x, y, z$, we can not ensure $x, y, z\ge 1$ (e.g the above example).

Answer (score 0):

If you trust in computer based proofs, this can be done with Maple >=2018 as follows. First, we numerically solve the optimization problem

```
Optimization:-Minimize((sqrt(a+1)+sqrt(1+b)+sqrt(1+c))/sqrt(a*b+a*c+b*c+6), {a >= 0, b >= 0, c >= 0, a*b*c+a+b+c = 4});
```

$$[ 1.41421356237309515,[a= 1.0,b= 1.0,c= 1.0]] $$

The above result suggests that the minimum $\sqrt 2$ is attained at $(a=1,b=1,c=1)$.

To check it, we eliminate $a$ from the target function by

```
solve(a*b*c+a+b+c = 4, a);
```

> `-(-4+b+c)/(b*c+1)`

```
f := eval((sqrt(a+1)+sqrt(1+b)+sqrt(1+c))/sqrt(a*b+a*c+b*c+6), a = -(-4+b+c)/(b*c+1));
```

> `f := (sqrt(-(-4+b+c)/(b*c+1)+1)+sqrt(1+b)+sqrt(1+c))/sqrt(-(-4+b+c)*b/(b*c+1)-c*(-4+b+c)/(b*c+1)+b*c+6)`

Third, we use the second derivative test with Maple by the command

```
Student:-MultivariateCalculus:-SecondDerivativeTest(f, [b, c] = [1, 1]);
```

> `LocalMin = [[1, 1]], LocalMax = [], Saddle = []`

Of course, all that may be mimicking by hand.

Addition. As I was informed by @V.S.e.H., this is a local minimum only. A global minimum can be found with

```
DirectSearch:-GlobalOptima((sqrt(a+1)+sqrt(1+b)+sqrt(1+c))/sqrt(a*b+a*c+b*c+6), {a >= 0, b >= 0, c >= 0, a*b*c+a+b+c = 4});
```

> `[1.41167288061134, [a = 1.99999839031817, b = 3.18835950887659*10^(-13), c = 2.00000161802040], 2167]`

The result suggests that three global minimums are attained at the corners of the triangle (the feasible set). Now we investigate the behavior of the target function on the side by usual tools of calculus with Maple.

```
eval((sqrt(a+1)+sqrt(1+b)+sqrt(1+c))/sqrt(a*b+a*c+b*c+6), {b = 0, c = 4-a});
```

> `(sqrt(a+1)+1+sqrt(5-a))/sqrt(6+a*(4-a))`

```
minimize((sqrt(a+1)+1+sqrt(5-a))/sqrt(6+a*(4-a)), a = 0 .. 4, location);
```

> `(1/10)*(2*sqrt(3)+1)*sqrt(10), {[{a = 2}, (1/10)*(2*sqrt(3)+1)*sqrt(10)]}`

There is no need to consider other sides because of symmetry. I repeat all that may be mimicked by hand.

Comment: The global minimum is not attained at $a=b=c=1$. MAPLE has found a local minimum, not a global one.